# One state lagging behind after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my React component, I have a function which calls `this.setState`, and updates a few states. However, one of them is always one state "behind", and I suspect it's because of how it's called.

Here is the function in which the states are set:

```
handleReps(reps) {
    var average = this.getAverage();
    this.setState({
        var1: CALCULATORS.epley(reps, this.state.weight),
        var2: CALCULATORS.brzycki(reps, this.state.weight),
        var3: CALCULATORS.lander(reps, this.state.weight),
        // some more
        average: average
    });
}
```

Now, all of these update fine, and are changed in the DOM, but the `average` state is always one cycle behind. That is to say, it always shows the value that it should have had BEFORE the last change. I.e. the last time `setState` was called.

Are there some known factors that might be causing this delay on one of the states?

EDIT: Here is the `getAverage()` function.

```
getAverage () {
    return CALCULATORS.average([
        this.state.epley, this.state.brzycki, this.state.lander,
        this.state.lombardi, this.state.mayhew, this.state.oconner,
        this.state.wathen
    ])
}
```

Comment: Is there something in the method this.getAverage(); that uses value from a variable, that is updated when the setState happens? If you can show getAverage code it could help to solve the problem, but my guess is that getAverage uses some variable that has not been updated after setState to return the average before it updates to you. Also you could check the react method componentDidUpdate to deal with it. Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate

Comment: @ViniciusVieira - Yes, the `getAverage` function uses ALL of the states that are set before the last one. Edited into question.

Comment: I think it's not related to getAverage, try to log the average in the reactjs methods componentDidUpdate and componentWillUpdate and check average values there, it should help to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here was two-fold.

As Igorsvee accurately pointed out, I was calculating the average using old states. Rookie mistake on my part.

The problem however, persisted after I started using "new" states. At that point, I learned that the states aren't mutating immediately, so even if I had the correct order, it was still using one-cycle-old states.

This was solved by passing a callback as a second argument to the `setState` function. This callback is called AFTER mutation, and will use brand new values.

Answer (score 2):

You use the current values from state to calculate the average, but at the same time you update the state with the new values.So,basically, you store the stale data for the average.I'd suggest to not store the calculated data, but rather invoke the method to calculate it, once you need it.

Comment: That was one of the problems, but also, the states weren't being mutated immediately, so even if I calculated the average using the "now-updated" states, it was still using the old values. I solved it by passing a callback to the `setState` function, which is called AFTER states have been mutated.